# Convert T4 Template to connect to MySQL database?

Tags: c#, mysql, poco, t4

I found the following `T4 Template` at http://www.haneycodes.net/automatically-generate-pocos-from-db-with-t4/ that connects to a `SqlServer database and generates POCO classes from the tables`.  I want to do the same thing with `MySql`, but I am not sure what I need to change. I tried just connecting with a MySqlConnection, but that didn't work.  Do I have to create a MySql Server instance?  If anyone knows an alternative to creating POCOs with MySQL, I am open to that as well.

```
<#@ template language="C#" hostspecific="true" debug="True" #> 
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #> <#@ assembly name="System.Data" #> 
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #> 
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo" #>
 <#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo" #> 
 <#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc" #> 
 <#@ import namespace="System" #> 
 <#@ import namespace="System.IO" #> 
 <#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #> 
 <#@ import namespace="System.Text" #> 
 <#@ import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo" #> 
 <#    

string sqlServer = "9.9.9.9";     
string sqlLogin = "admin";     
string sqlPassword = "password";     
string sqlDatabase = "MyDatabase";     
string classNamespace = "Your.Namespace.Here";     
string destinationFolder = "PocoFolder";       


Server server = new Server(sqlServer);     
server.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = false;     
server.ConnectionContext.Login = sqlLogin;    
server.ConnectionContext.Password = sqlPassword;     
server.ConnectionContext.Connect();       

foreach (Table table in server.Databases[sqlDatabase].Tables)    
{        

     if (table.Name.StartsWith("sys"))         
     {             
         continue;         

     } #> 

     using System;  

     namespace <#= classNamespace #> 
     {     

     public class <#= table.Name #>      
     { <#          
             int columnCount = table.Columns.Count;        
      int i = 0;                   
     foreach (Column col in table.Columns)        
      {             
          i++;             
          string propertyType = GetNetDataType(col.DataType.Name);               
          // If we can't map it, skip it             
          if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyType))             
          {                 
              // Skip                 
              continue;             
          }               
          // Handle nullable columns by making the type nullable             
          if (col.Nullable && propertyType != "string")             
          {                
               propertyType += "?";             
          } #>         
          public <#= propertyType #> <#= col.Name #> { get; set; } <#            
           // Do we insert the space?            
           if (i != columnCount)             
           { #> <#             
           } #> <#         
      } #>     
      } 
      }       
      <#         
      // Write new POCO class to its own file         
      SaveOutput(table.Name + ".cs", destinationFolder);     
}  #> 
<#+     
public static string GetNetDataType(string sqlDataTypeName)     
{         switch (sqlDataTypeName.ToLower())         
    {             
    case "bigint":                
         return "Int64";             
    case "binary":             
    case "image":             
    case "varbinary":                 
        return "byte[]";             
    case "bit":                 
        return "bool";             
    case "char":                 
        return "char";             
    case "datetime":             
    case "smalldatetime":                 
        return "DateTime";             
    case "decimal":             
    case "money":             
    case "numeric":                 
        return "decimal";             
    case "float":                 
        return "double";             
    case "int":                 
        return "int";             
    case "nchar":             
    case "nvarchar":             
    case "text":             
    case "varchar":             
    case "xml":                 
        return "string";             
    case "real":                
         return "single";          
       case "smallint":             
            return "Int16";         
        case "tinyint":             
            return "byte";          
       case "uniqueidentifier":     
                    return "Guid";  
                                 default:              
           return null;         
    }     
}       

void SaveOutput(string outputFileName, string destinationFolder)   
  {         
      // Write to destination folder       
        string templateDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile), destinationFolder);         string outputFilePath = Path.Combine(templateDirectory, outputFileName);        
       File.Delete(outputFilePath);      
         File.WriteAllText(outputFilePath, this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString());          
        // Flush generation         
      this.GenerationEnvironment.Remove(0, this.GenerationEnvironment.Length);    
   } #>
```

Comment: Why go through all the trouble when you have EF?

Comment: @DionV. - I can't use EF.  I am going to use `Dapper`, but I don't want to have to hand code all the POCO files.

Answer (score 0):

I used the [db schema reader project](http://dbschemareader.codeplex.com/) in my VS extenion ([T4 Awesome](https://www.t4awesome.com)) to access the database structure.  It supports any of the ADO providers. You can download the MySql provider [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).  The docs on the the db schema reader project are pretty good so you should be able to use them to figure out how to connect to the database and read the structure.

As I said I implemented this in my extension so if you want a quick solution, you can just [download it](https://www.t4awesome.com) and give it a try.  If not, you pretty much do it the same way you already have but reference the db schema reader projects namespaces and assemblies.